# How to add none Jar Libraries to Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an android project that consist of .jar file's library and some library project's that have not any gradle file's, when i import this project in Android studio i faced to some error's that tell me this librarie's are not applied how can solve this problem?

[image: screen shot of my problem]

Comment: please take a screen shot of your error's

Comment: The fact that your errors complain about missing resources tell me that your libraries cannot be JARs. JARs cannot contain Android resources.

Comment: There is another thread about this. You can look into that

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

To add a Jar Dependency in Android Studio. put that jar file in Your project-->app-->libs folder. and then follow these steps

1. Go to File --> Project Structure
2. On the left hand side you will see app module. click on that and then on the right hand side select Dependencies tab
3. Now click (+) button on the right
4. Select file dependency
5. A dialog will appear that let you choose your jar file
6. select the jar you want to add and click ok. DONE

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure all your modules that have the support library as dependency also have the compile SDK set to 21 . So go to Project Structure and check all the modules on the left hand side.